# MAAS for old hardware and Ubuntu for video production

Tags: juju, maas, ubuntu-studio

I'm an enthusiast newbie that runs a small (new born) video production company on the 3rth world... We have a mixed old hardware environment (about 6 machines from Intel P4 to core 2 duo).

I want to pull together this machines with MAAS (as a single server)
Then run Ubuntu (maybe Ubuntu Studio) with Kdenlive, Cinelerra, The Gimp, Audacity, Darktable, LireOffice, Mozilla Firefox and few other programs.
Then use thin clients to connect and run the applications directly on the server, optimizing this way the resources usage.

Is this possible?

Is this good?

or maybe I misunderstood the MAAS purpose.

If someone can enlight me on the way to achieve this I will be very happy.

Thanks in advance.

PS.
Excuse me for my English, is not my mother language :)

Answer (score 0):

MAAS can help you to provision your machines, i.e you can power on/off, install OS e.g Ubuntu on your machines. To install the programs that you listed should be possible using juju charms. You might have to write a charm that installs the packages on machines.

[MAAS documentation](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/)

[Juju documentation](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started)

Comment: Tank you very much for your advice, provisioning and cetralized management in very usefull, but I hope MAAS could helpme to do more tha just that.

Comment: What I really want to do with MAAS is to use all the computers as a single server running Ubuntu and the applications mentioned before, and use thin clients to connect and run the applications directly on the server, optimizing this way the resources usage. 

Now my questions again:
Is MAAS suitable for that use?
There is a better way to do it?
Did I miss something?

And again Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally ad after some research I found that I was looking for was a "Beowulf cluster" or "distributed operating system", and MAAS is NOT intended for that.

In fact no one of this solutions is really useful for enhance the overall performance running the kind of applications I want to run but are useful for very specific scientific applications.

In conclusion, what I really need to do is upgrade my hardware.